# Is there any software that can verify my iPhone has original Apple hardware?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any software that can verify my iPhone has original Apple hardware, such as the display is original, the battery, etc.?

**Note:** Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out. I forgot the name of the software. Finally, I was able to find it. This software shows what parts are replaced in your iPhone and jailbreaked (what it actually does is check the factory serial numbers and hardware serial numbers, if anything is different that will consider as replaced). http://www.3u.com/

Answer (score 12):

Since iOS 15.2, there's a replaced parts list in Settings > General > About.

[image]
<sub>Picture - 9to5Mac</sub>

This section only appears if any parts have been changed, otherwise it remains hidden. If the phone is relatively new, your Warranty status will appear here instead.

See [9to5Mac - iOS 15.2 shows a service history of repaired parts in your iPhone](https://9to5mac.com/2021/12/08/ios-15-2-shows-a-service-history-of-repaired-parts-in-your-iphone/) for more information.

As mentioned in comments, this applies only to the iPhone XR & later - [Apple KB - iPhone parts and service history](https://support.apple.com/HT212878)

Comment: The iOS version seems to be not the only requirements. My iPhoneX on 15.4 does not show any of the shown entries.

Comment: Has it ever had any parts replaced? As noted above, it doesn't show unless it has. I no longer have a 2nd device I can check this on. My old 6S showed the battery had been replaced, my current SE2 shows the Warranty info.

Comment: This feature is available in models only as recent as iPhone XR and its scope is limited to certain parts as this "[iPhone parts and service history](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212878)" Apple support webpage explains. So, for example, even if @Robert's iPhone X had its battery replaced, no corresponding entry would appear in Settings > General > About.

Comment: @Alper - sorry, hadn't spotted that. Added to answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No - you would need access to the serial numbers of internal parts as assembled in the factory and also access to the current serial numbers of installed parts to begin with. And then you'd have to deal with counterfeit / bogus labels on the parts and also replacement parts savvy enough to be reprogrammed to have the same serials as the parts that were present at assembly.

Only major service parts are listed by the OS itself currently, but perhaps Apple would go this way if they want to reinforce the value of authorized repairs as they open up DIY repair parts to anyone willing to register and pay for them. The right to repair movement has some great philosophical aspects, but in practice it has a large amount of right to despair when people over estimate their skill level or the cost and time of tooling to redo repairs the first dozen or more times you attempt some of the more delicate operations needed to service modern tablets and phones.